# HasOne relationship in laravel with a "through" table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship, laravel-8

I'm currently having a problem with relationships.

I have 3 tables:

- factions:

  - id
- roles:

  - id
- faction_roles:

  - faction_id
  - role_id

Every faction has many roles but every role only has 1 faction. I already thought about creating a faction_id column in my roles table, but I wanted to solve it with only faction_roles, so I don't have to add data to 2 tables.

My role model looks like that:

```php
 public function faction()
 {
    return $this->hasOne(Faction::class, 'faction_roles.faction_id', 'faction_roles.role_id');
 }
```

I already tried it with $this->belongsTo(Faction::class), but didn't work aswell.

Thanks in advance!

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see the problem, if you define the relationship like you did in Faction model:

```
public function factions() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Faction::class);
}
```

Then the relationship method is going to return one item, you can query the first element of the relationship if you want like this:

```
$role->factions->first();
```

Or:

```
$role->factions()->first();
```

See [Eager loading for the difference](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)

What else do you need exactly?

Comment: But it doesn't belongs to many factions, just to one. So is there a way to get $role->faction working without getting a collection of roles and just get 1 role?

Comment: But the fact is that it does belong to many, so a workaround could be creating another class method that only returns the faction of the role, but it won't be treated as a relationship.

Comment: I think I found a workaround by using an accessor. So return $role->factions->first(). That atleast cleanes up my code. Thanks for your answers :)

Comment: Alright, just come back if you need anything, and please vote or mark the answer as correct :)